# Check for a domain

Tags: security, dns

How can I test whether the request for an API is coming from the correct registered domain.

Answer (score 1):

You cant.

You can check the IP from the server, but 1 server can handle $n domains..

I've tested with google: token my google map api key, he just ping the domain i give and retrieve the server IP; but the api key is valid from every domain on that server...while changing server (another one with different IP) the same api key return an error

Comment: A domain can also resolve to multiple IP addresses (e.g. via round robin DNS base load balancing)

Comment: Also IP addresses can be faked. And if the API call has an immediate effect server-side, there is no need to send a valid source IP.

Comment: I did configure a virtual host here in `localhost` and I configured a facebook API to add my "host" and that's ok, how would facebook ping my local ip address?

Comment: @GiovanneAfonso you cant, unless you have a static IP address and a DNS pointing on it with the domain name.

Comment: @Strae I can, try by yourself. Maybe local access is free or it's free because sandbox mode was activated or something like that, I don't know.